# Removing dashed lines in range input in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a range input like this:

```css
.my-slider {
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: white;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.my-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-slider::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="275" value="0" class="my-slider" id="myRange">
```

Things are looking fine except that when I click on the thumb, 2 dashed lines appear, which look like this:

[image]

I have tried adding `border: none` and `outline: none` rules to remove these, to no avail. This happens in Firefox only, the dashed lines don't show in Chrome.

Anyone know how to remove the dashed lines? Thanks!

Comment: seems fine on Firefox for me

Comment: Have you tried to focus the thumb?

Comment: yes ...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `::-moz-focus-outer` selector.

```
input[type=range]::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0
}
```